# How can i list all ELB's in my AWS account

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I am trying to find out if there is a way to browse all ELB's for a ios app i am working on.I found a describeloadbalancer method in the aws api, but that requires me to know the load balancer's name. I want to know if there is a way to list all the ELB's associated with my AWS account.

I noticed that there is a aws console app that allows users to browse their elastic load balancers, so im guessing there must be a way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding DescribeLoadBalancers, are you certain of that behavior?  The [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeLoadBalancers.html) suggests otherwise, by default:

> Returns detailed configuration information for **all the load balancers** created for the account.

If you specify the load balancers name, the returned results should be limited to those sets of load balancers that you specified:

> If you specify load balancer names, the action returns configuration information of the specified load balancers.

Here's a link for [the related documentation in AWS SDK for iOS 7.1](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/AmazonElasticLoadBalancingClient.html#//api/name/describeLoadBalancers%3a), if you're interested.  It seems to me that this should work fine if you simply do not request any specific ELB names.

Comment: I had tested this before, but it didnt work. Turns out you need to change the default AZ from us-east-1. Theres isnt a method to change it so i didnt think about that. THANKS !